# particles presentation in the particle filter

Tags: tracking, detection, sample, vehicle-routing, particle-filter

in the particle filter algorithm, particles should present as a dots or it can be represented as rectangle boxes? in the case of rectangle boxes, how I can determine the box size? if the object is far from the camera I want to show an object with a small box (particle), but when it is near the camera with a bog rectangle box (particle)

Answer (score 0):

A particle is an element of the search space. If the search space is defined as the set of all possible positions (as in classical partical filters used for localization problems in mobile robotic) a particle is a position in this search space, aka a dot.
If you define the search space as set of all possible rectangles, a particle would represent a rectangle and therefore can be represented as one.
Thus, it sorely depends on the implementation of the particle filter.